# iOS App being rejected by apple after upload - Invalid Checksum

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, app-store

I uploaded my app but it was declared as invalid with following error:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   "Business Card Scanner Pro". Please correct the following issues, then
>   upload again.
>
> Invalid Checksum - The provided checksum
>   [6c004f9ee372e240d11cd2b3afba439a] does not match the computed
>   checksum [517819be1b7c175fb7d861faff7ab761] for asset 'BCScanner2.ipa'
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

Does anybody know a way to get through this issue? Any workarounds?

Comment: Did you find out a solution?